# Is using hidden inputs a valid way to retrieve php variables in an external JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a couple external JavaScript files that need to access variables from php that were retrieved from MySQL. The way they are currently being access is through hidden input tags such as this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myVar" value="<?php echo($myVar); ?>">
```

In the JavaScript I can then really easily access the php variable `$myVar`.

Doing some research I discovered that having hidden input tags outside of a form is perfectly valid, so I cannot see why this approach might be flawed. I do know that using ajax is another solution but seems silly since this page is built on the fly, why hit the database again? Are there any issues with this method that scream "don't do this"? I am new to JavaScript and relatively so to HTML so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Why not output valid JS code from PHP already – f.e. one JavaScript variable, that gets the values passed as JSON …

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be honest I don't like your approach. To insert a PHP variable to a external javascript file I always do the following.

```
<script>var myVar = "<?= $myVar ?>";</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myJsFile.js"></script>
```

You than can access `myVar` in your external `myJsFile.js`

Comment: Some servers can't use the <?= short open code, and will instead need to use "<?php echo $myVar; ?>"

Comment: To be honest, I don't like your approach either, because it puts the variables in global scope....

Comment: This approach will be very helpful in the future. The issue I see with this in the context of my application is that I have an unknown number of instances of these hidden inputs (built with a loop in php). I access them using jQuery's $.each functionality, each instance is used by a different thread.

Comment: @user3043546 You can create any js expression here, e.g. an array filled by the php loop

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use cookies ? Set your variables in your PHP functions/modules and access the same variables from the Javascript later on the client browser, you can use the jQuery cookie plug-in too for a fatser code writing, jQuery: http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/, PHP: http://php.net/manual/fr/features.cookies.php